# Spaces on Dynamic PIVOT column name in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot

I have this very simple example:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when NAME = ''',
      NAME,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      replace(NAME, ' ', '_')
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM
  sourcetable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Date, ', @sql, ' from sourcetable group by date');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Full example: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2acd7bcde542bfb2d2619475b3175813)

I would like the column names in the PIVOT table to match exactly the names that were previously in the NAME column with all characters that were previously there. For some reason I need this presentation because it is used in another system.

How can I solve this? Some kind of another replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap up the aliases with **accent graves** rather than replacing ***whitespaces*** with ***underscores*** such as

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
          CONCAT('MAX( CASE WHEN name = ''',NAME,''' THEN value END) AS `',NAME,'`')
  )
  INTO @sql 
  FROM sourcetable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Date, ', @sql, ' FROM sourcetable GROUP BY date');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=70fede91e809cba72898e1da090ff4c1)</kbd>